# Where shall I place SET time_zone = 'America/New_York'

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

How do I query MySQL by this class and SET time_zone after every query? I'm having some trouble about where to place the timezone command in the following code block:

```
class MyDB {

    private $connection;
    public $last_query;
    private $magic_quotes_active;
    private $real_escape_string_exists;
    function __construct(){
        $this->open_connection();
        $this->magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
        $this->real_escape_string_exists = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string");
    }

    public function open_connection(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->connection){
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_connect());
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if(!$db_select){
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());

            }
        }
    }

    public function close_connection(){
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->last_query = $sql;   
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);     
        $this->confirm_query($result);      
        return $result;
    }

    public function escape_value($value){
        if($this->real_escape_string_exists){ // PHP v.4.3.0 or higher
            //undo any magic quote effects so mysl_real_escape_string can do the work
            if($this->magic_quotes_active){
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            }
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        } else { // before PHP v.4.3.0
            // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
            if(!$this->magic_quotes_active) {
                $value = addslashes($value);
            }
            // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function fetch_array($result_set){
        return mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
    }

    public function num_rows($result_set){
        return mysql_num_rows($result_set);
    }

    public function insert_id($result_set){
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows($result_set){
        return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }

    private function confirm_query($result){
        if(!$result){
            $output = "Database query failed: " . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
            $output .= "Last SQL query: ". $this->last_query;
            die($output);
        }

    }
}
```

$database = new MyDB();
$db =& $database;

Answer (score 0):

You could set it on the fly like this: 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

Comment: I've tried that and it does not fit my purpose. I'd like to set it after every mysql query.

Comment: As far as setting it in that codeblock... I was thinking you wanted to change the timezone to different ones, not just leave it at New_York? If you are leaving it at New_York just set that in the php.ini

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to set it after every query? I don't think it is going to act correctly doing that... but out of curiosity... why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Just for the heck of it... I can say you probably could add what I said above in the initial answer in the query function in that class.

`code`public function query($sql) {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $this->last_query = $sql;   
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);     
        $this->confirm_query($result);      
        return $result;
    }`code`

Comment: I'm following the suggestions here, but his code is different from mine:

https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/

As you can see in my implementation in my template site: http://facegod.us/fg/index.php the dates are returning "FOUR DAYS AGO", when it should show FOUR YEARS AGO.

I have no problem in my local system, but I have that problem in my host as is the case.

Comment: In fact, date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'): is already at the top of the page;

Comment: if it shows days instead of years, it shouldn't be a timezone problem, Maybe system time is wrong? How is the diff computed?